# Integrating Pig 0.16.0 UDF with Eclipse

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig.

Can anyone tell me how to integrate Pig UDF with Eclipse and from where to download the UDF jar file?

map reduce code works fine for me in Eclipse.

Comment: Download what JAR file?

Comment: jar file required to run user defined function(UDF) in pig i saw the video on youtube but did know from where he downloaded the udf file. Link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BAtxOs1q2o

Comment: That video wrote Java code and **built** a JAR file. It was not downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Eclipse > New Maven Project.
2. Edit `pom.xml`. 
   Add to dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
       <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
       <version>0.16.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. [**Write code** for a UDF](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/udf.html#udf-java)
4. Use Eclipse or the terminal to run `mvn clean package`
5. Copy JAR file onto Hadoop node, or HDFS.
6. Run `REGISTER` Pig command
7. Use UDF